# Replacing using regex in a string javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to replace a particular string using regex.

```
var replace = {'&lt;RAndom&gt;': "random object"};
```

I am replacing it using the dynamic regex because i have a lot of objects.

```
var tagsText = "&lt;RAndom&gt; hellow world";
var regex = new RegExp('\\b(' + Object.keys(replace).join('|') + ')\\b', 'g');
tagsText = tagsText.replace(regex, function(match) {
    return replace[match] + match;
});
```

But it is not working.I think the problem is with the semicolon but i am not sure.The output is again the same.

```
"&lt;RAndom&gt; hellow world"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You should remove the `\\b`s or replace with `(^|\\W)` and `(\\W|$)` respecitively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word boundary `\b` and non-word boundary assertion behavior depends on the context. Make it context-independent with unambiguous `(^|\W)` and `($|\W)`:

```js
var replace = {'&lt;RAndom&gt;': "random object"};
var tagsText = "&lt;RAndom&gt; hellow world";
var regex = new RegExp('(^|\\W)(' + Object.keys(replace).join('|') + ')(\\W|$)', 'g');
tagsText = tagsText.replace(regex, function(match, g1, g2, g3) {
    return replace[g2] ? replace[g2] + match : match;
});
// And just a demo below
document.body.innerHTML = "<pre>" + tagsText.replace(/&/g, '&amp;') + "</pre>";
```

The `(^|\W)` will match the start of string or a non-word character. The `($|\W)` will match the end of the string or a non-word character.

Since we have 3 groups now, we can pass them as arguments to the replace callback. With `replace[g2] ? replace[g2] + match : match;`, we first check if there is a value for `g2` key, and if yes, perform the replacement. Else, just return the `match`.

Comment: Thanks for the awesome explanation :)

Answer (score 2):

Problem is presence of `\b` (word boundary) on each side that is placed before `&` and `;`. Both `&` and `;` are not non-word characters and `\b` cannot be asserted before and after non-word chars.

You can use `\B` instead:

```
var regex = new RegExp('\\B(' + Object.keys(replace).join('|') + ')\\B', 'g');
```

and then

```
tagsText  = tagsText.replace(regex, function(match) {
    return replace[match] + match;
});

//=> "random object&lt;RAndom&gt; hellow world"
```

Comment: If a key starts or ends with a word character, this will fail.

Comment: Right in that case OP's code would have worked. I guess more details needed from OP about the intent behind `\b` and more examples.

Comment: Or use my solution that is context-independent. Kind of :)